# Extend Core Model in Magento

Tags: php, magento, model, magento-1.5

I'm trying to extend: Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility

I'm modifying the following in the Visibility.php file:

```
public function getVisibleInSiteIds()
  {
    return array(self::VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH, self::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG, self::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
  }
```

Into:

```
public function getVisibleInSiteIds()
  {
    return array(self::VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH, self::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG, self::VISIBILITY_BOTH, self::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE);
  }
```

Outdated products that are set to Not Visible will still show from their direct URL (by default Magento would show a 404).

I tested this by modifying the core file and it works. But I'd like to create a little extension and so far I can't get it to work. This is what I've done so far:

app/etc/modules/CustomCode_InvisibleProducts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
   <modules>
     <CustomCode_InvisibleProducts>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
     </CustomCode_InvisibleProducts>
   </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/CustomCode/InvisibleProducts/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <CustomCode_InvisibleProducts>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </CustomCode_InvisibleProducts>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <customcode_invisibleproducts>
                <class>CustomCode_InvisibleProducts_Model</class>
            </customcode_invisibleproducts>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_visibility>CustomCode_InvisibleProducts_Model_Catalog_Product_Visibility</product_visibility>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/CustomCode/InvisibleProducts/Model/Catalog/Product/Visibility.php

```
class CustomCode_InvisibleProducts_Model_Catalog_Product_Visibility extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility
{
     .....
```

Somehow I'm not extending the Model correctly because nothing seems to be happening/changing.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you make sure that the module got loaded? You can see a list in "System" -> "Configuration" -> "Advanced" -> "Disable Module Output". If it does not appear there, delete the Magento cache and try again.

Comment: Yes I did, it's there and it's enabled. Caching is turned off btw.

Comment: The rewrite configuration looks right to me. My next step would be to determine if the overridden method gets called (with a debugger or call to `Mage::log()` in the method)

Comment: Hi Fab! I'm don't know how to do either of them

Comment: I did add Mage::logo('Test') to the Visibility.php file, but nothing is showing up in the system log file. So I'm guessing somehow, I'm not extending/overwriting the Model in the proper way. Anybody got a clue to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I proceeded to add Mage::log('Test2') to the original Visibility.php file, this time, logs are showing up. This confirms that Magento still uses the original Visibility.php. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've changed the name of the extension from CustomCode_InvisibleProducts to CustomCode_Visible, because I didn't know what else to do.

And somehow, the extension started working right away.

Final code:

app/etc/modules/CustomCode_Visible.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <CustomCode_Visible>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
    </CustomCode_Visible>
  </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/CustomCode/Visible/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <CustomCode_Visible>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </CustomCode_Visible>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <customcode_visible>
                <class>CustomCode_Visible_Model</class>
            </customcode_visible>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_visibility>CustomCode_Visible_Model_Catalog_Product_Visibility</product_visibility>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/CustomCode/Model/Catalog/Product/Visibility.php

```
class CustomCode_Visible_Model_Catalog_Product_Visibility extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility
{

  ....

        public function getVisibleInSiteIds()
    {
        return array(self::VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH, self::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG, self::VISIBILITY_BOTH, self::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: Right above your last code block you have `app/code/local/CustomCode/Model/Catalog/Product/Visibility.php`. Shouldn't it be `app/code/local/CustomCode/Visible/Model/Catalog/Product/Visibility.php` ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't declare your module in your config.xml

```
<modules>
    <CustomCode_InvisibleProducts>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </CustomCode_InvisibleProducts>
</modules>
```

Insert this before your global node.

Comment: Thanks a lot dagfr, just made the change. However, I still don't get any output.